# Running Create Table SQL command in Android

Tags: android, sql

Following on from my previous question about tables I am trying to create additional tables on my database in Android.

Basically, I would like a database to be created which is done so by this code:

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }
```

Then when a user adds an account I would like a table added with the name of the account the user entered. I try to call the createTable() method I created.

```
 public void createAccount(String account) {
        DATABASE_TABLE = account;
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        System.out.println(DATABASE_NAME);      
}
```

But the db doesn't work as eclipse cannot find the variable. I try mDb which is my SQLiteDatabase but I get a null pointer exception.

*Edit*

I really can't get my head around the database. I am using the For Dummies book and a Database helper but from where I am at now I feel a lot of the code is done behind the scenes and it is hard to follow.

This is part of my database class:

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        System.out.println(DATABASE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void createAccount(String account) {
        DATABASE_TABLE = account;
        /*   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("create table long ("
                + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + KEY_DESCRIPTION + " text not null, " 
                + KEY_DEBIT + " text not null);");   
    }       
}
```

At the bottom of the class I have

```
public void changeDatabase(String account) {
    DATABASE_TABLE = account;
    mDbHelper.createAccount(account);
}
```

which is called upon from my createAccount class.

I am getting a null point exception.

Comment: can you share the createTable method?

Comment: Soham, the createAccount is the createTable method. My fault sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is without seeing your code...

I'm guessing you've inherited / extended from one of the SQLite Classes.

you see how you've implemented onCreate() and are provided the database as a parameter,

if you create a new function, like that createAccount function you need to get a handle of the db as follows:-

```
 public void createAccount(String account) {
    DATABASE_TABLE = account;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
    System.out.println(DATABASE_NAME);      
}
```

- Anthony

Comment: Anthony Thanks for that it was very helpful. I am still having issues and have updated my first post.

Comment: Where is mDBHelper set? I cannot see this in the code you supplied. If that last function is in the same class as the other methods, just call the function directly. Also there's is a stray /* in the code commenting out several lines. also DATABASE_TABLE needs using in the create table command if you want to create a table for each username.

Comment: Anthony, Thanks again. The mDBHelper was set at the top of the file and the /* wasn't in my actual code. 

Got it working I think. I forgot to open the database! Ooops.

Comment: Turns out I still have a strange issue. I am trying to change the DATABASE_TABLE VARIABLE and do so via a method.

    `public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
         System.out.println(DATABASE_TABLE);
         System.out.println(TABLE_CREATE);
         db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        }`

When I run this command, The first line prints out the DATABASE_TABLE correctly, while the second and third line refer to DATABASE_TABLE = null.

Comment: You need to build table_create it's not set anywhere. You need a line like table_create = “CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (.....)“; where ..... is your field definition(s)

Comment: It is declared, sorry I just didn't post it as I ran out of charachters. Here is the entire class http://pastebin.com/UmJ1PtsX

Comment: TABLE_CREATE should be set every time the DATABASE_NAME is set, ie don't make it final, as it will just be set to contain the initial value of DATABASE_NAME (NULL).